# How to use npm version to increment the counter behind the prepatch / preid suffix

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

I'm trying to find out how to correctly use `npm version` with prepatch (also premajor or preminor) / preid options to increment the counter behind the suffix.

e.g.:

- I have a `v.0.5.22` and want to append `-rc`
- I used the command `npm version prepatch --preid rc`
- then I get `v.0.5.23-rc.0`, fine so far.
- but the next time I'm using the same command I end up with `v.0.5.24-rc.0`,
- what I want  is to get `v.0.5.23-rc.1` instead

How can I only increment the counter behind `-rc.` and keep the patch number?
Or am I misunderstanding the purpose of prepatch / preid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, I'll answer my own question for future reference.

After having `v.0.5.23-rc.0` the command to only bump the number behind the . has to be:

`npm version prerelease`

Then I would get `v.0.5.23-rc.1`.

Comment: TIL: better never use underscores in the preid. npm version will fail silently after that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `npm version` would be to write a bash script.

Ended up with this, fetching the version from the package.json

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

packageJsonLocation="../package.json"
current_version=$(grep '"version":' $packageJsonLocation | cut -d\" -f4)
pre=0

if [ -z "${current_version}" ]; then
  echo "No version found in package.json"
  exit 1
fi

if [[ $current_version =~ ^.*-.* ]]; then
  # increment prerelease version
  IFS='-' read -ra array_pre <<< "$current_version"
  IFS='.' read -ra array <<< "${array_pre[0]}"
  pre=$(( ${array_pre[1]} + 1))
else 
  IFS='.' read -ra array <<< "${current_version}"
fi

new_version="${array[0]}.${array[1]}.${array[2]}-${pre}"

echo "Pre version: ${current_version} -> ${new_version}"
```

```bash
# Output
2.9.3   -> 2.9.3-0
and
2.9.3-1 -> 2.9.3-2
```

Comment: Well, my question was clearly about npm version. Seems like a bit overcomplicated instead of just using the built-in feature.